# @Around advice returning correct response but at client side response is null or undefined

Tags: spring, undefined, response, aop

I am trying to apply Around advice to my "Login.jsp" with angular js. And the problem is my controller method is check and I am applying around advice to check method but when I run my application I will get undefined as response at Login.jsp. And but the result which I had printed in my advice contains expected result.But I am not getting it on client side.

**AroundAdvice.java**

```java
@Aspect @Component
public class AroundAdvice {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AfterLoginAspect.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* com.admin.controller.LoginController.check(..))")
    public void logWrittter(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        SimpleDateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat();
        log.info("Date Time :: " + date.format(new Date().getTime()));
        Object result = jp.proceed();
        System.out.println("result around");
        log.info("result :: " + result);
        // returns {"get Status":"home"}
    }
}
```

**LoginController.jsp**

```java
// authentication check
@RequestMapping(value = "/PostFormData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JSONObject check(@RequestBody LoginBo login) {
    System.out.println("checkCredentials::" + login.getUserName());

    String username = login.getUserName();
    // log.info("uswername ::"+username);

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    String encrptedpassword = encryptdPwd.encrypt(login.getPassWord());

    boolean login_status = loginService.checkCredentials(username, encrptedpassword);
    // log.info("login_status ::"+login_status);
    // System.out.println("staus ::"+login_status);

    if (login_status == true && login.isIs_system_generated_pwd() == true) {
        System.out.println("sys gen chnge pwd:: " + login.isIs_system_generated_pwd());
        result.put("getStatus", "change");
        // System.out.println(resultPage);
        // login.setIs_system_generated_pwd(false);
    } else if (login_status == true && login.isIs_system_generated_pwd() == false) {
        result.put("getStatus", "home");
        // System.out.println("Home paege ");
    } else {
        result.put("getStatus", "error");

    }
    System.out.println("result ::" + result);
    // log.info("result ::"+resultPage);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have reformatted your question so as to make it at least readable. But please update it in order to help me and others to understand what you have actually asked. For instance, I really do not understand how Angular JS is involved in all of this. For me it looks like a Java and AspectJ (or Spring AOP) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointcut does not match because the advice has a `void` return type, but your method returns a `JSONObject`. So maybe you want to change your advice declaration to:

```java
@Aspect @Component
public class AroundAdvice {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AfterLoginAspect.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* com.admin.controller.LoginController.check(..))")
    public JSONObject logWriter(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        SimpleDateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat();
        log.info("Date Time :: " + date.format(new Date().getTime()));
        JSONObject result = (JSONObject) jp.proceed();
        System.out.println("result around");
        log.info("result :: " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Please note

- `public JSONObject logWriter` instead of `public void logWrittter`,
- `JSONObject result = (JSONObject) jp.proceed();` instead of `Object result = jp.proceed();` and
- `return result;` instead of no return value.

Comment: hii @kriegaex  thanks its working for me.                              @Around("execution(* com.admin.controller.LoginController.check(..))")
 public JSONObject logWrittter(ProceedingJoinPoint  jp) throws Throwable
  {
         SimpleDateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat();
   System.out.println("Date Time ::"+date.format(new Date().getTime()));

   log.info("Date Time ::"+date.format(new Date().getTime()));
   Object obj =jp.proceed();
   System.out.println("result aroud end ascpect applied "+obj);
   log.info("result :: "+obj);
  return (JSONObject) obj;
 }

Comment: Just found this again by chance and fixed a copy & paste error in code and notes.